# How to convert VARCHAR value for '1:00 PM' (time only) to TIME as '13:00' using a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, time, casting

I have a VARCHAR column in table, containing time value in a format as '1:00 PM'. I need to convert it to TIME format like '13:00'.

I tried below queries but nothing worked -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(pickup_time, '%H:%i') as pt FROM `tbl_name`;
```

Returned 'NULL'.

```
SELECT CAST(pickup_time as time) as pt FROM `tbl_name`;
```

Returned '01:00'.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CAST(pickup_time as time), '%H:%i') as pt FROM `tbl_name`;
```

Returned 'NULL'.

Expected output is **'13:00'**.

Comment: `select str_to_date('1:00 PM','%h:%i %p');`   see: [STR_TO_DATE and DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: or maybe a better answer is: `select date_format(str_to_date('1:00 PM','%h:%i %p'),'%H:%i');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some logic in query to get expected result as below -

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING_INDEX((CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ', -1)='PM') THEN CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ':', 1)+12), ':',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ', 1),':',-1)) ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ',1) END),':',1)) <= 9 THEN CONCAT('0',(CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ', -1)='PM') THEN CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ':', 1)+12), ':',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ', 1),':',-1)) ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ',1) END)) ELSE (CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ', -1) = 'PM') THEN CONCAT((SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ':', 1)+12), ':',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ', 1),':',-1)) ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(pickup_time, ' ',1) END) END) as pt from `tbl_name`;
```

This returns result as '13:00' if column value is '1:00 PM'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1:00 PM', '%h:%i %p');
```

Returns: 13:00:00

And the mistake was when using AM/PM format the hours lie till 12 not 24. So, when you are using %H its giving you the same hour irrespective to AM/PM.

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1:00 PM', '%h:%i %p'); --- This return NULL

Comment: I am using Mysql 8.0. And I am able to get the desired answer. I tried to simulate with online Mysql playground and its working there too. Reference: https://extendsclass.com/mysql-online.html